# Swift return object of type from an array containing class elements

Tags: arrays, swift, object, generics, subclass

Here is a small code I wrote to explain the problem:

```
class Vehicle{
    var name:String = ""
    var tyres: Int = 0

}

class Bus:Vehicle{
    var make:String = "Leyland"
}

class Car: Vehicle{
    var model:String = "Polo"
}

let myVehicles:[Vehicle] = [
    Vehicle(),
    Car(),
    Bus()
]

for aVehicle in myVehicles{
    if(aVehicle is Bus){
        print("Bus found")
    }
}
```

From the code, I can loop through and get the object of type `Bus`. However, I need a function to do the same thing and return the element of that type if available. I tried using generics but it does not work. I will need something like this:

```
func getVehicle(type:T.type)->T?{
 // loop through the array, find if the object is of the given type.
 // Return that type object.
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `foo as? T` to try to cast `foo` as type `T`.

```
for aVehicle in myVehicles{
    if let bus = aVehicle as? Bus {
        print("Bus found", bus.make)
    }
}
```

---

Your `getVehicle` can thus be written as:

```
func getVehicle<T>() -> T? {
    for aVehicle in myVehicles {
        if let v = aVehicle as? T {
            return v
        }
    }
    return nil
}

let bus: Bus? = getVehicle()
```

or functionally:

```
func getVehicle<T>() -> T? {
    return myVehicles.lazy.flatMap { $0 as? T }.first
}
let bus: Bus? = getVehicle()
```

(Note that we need to specify the returned variable as `Bus?` so `getVehicle` can infer the `T`.)

Comment: So, I dont have to specify any class type for this method?

Comment: @Nareshkumar. The method is generic. Which type of vehicle is used is inferred from the type of the variable to which it is assigned. See kennytm writes `let bus: Bus? = getVehicle()` not just `let bus = getVehicle()`. It's the explicit type of `bus` that pickes the right `T`

Answer (score 3):

You can write it like this :

```
 func getVehicle<T>(type:T)-> [T]{
    return myVehicles.filter{ $0 is T }.map{$0 as! T }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this:

```
func getVehicle<T>(type: T.Type) -> T? {
  return myVehicles.filter { Swift.type(of: $0) == type }.first as? T
}
```

Usage:

```
getVehicle(type: Bus.self)
```

Comment: T has no member `init`

Comment: I've updated it so that it should compile now

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this:

```
let a = array.compactMap({ $0 as? MyTypeClass })
// a == [MyTypeClass] no optional
```